# c++ linked list delete function leaving a hole

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime

for my final programming project, I needed to create a linked list to hold items, and it needs to be able to delete and add items. Appending the items to linked list works fine, but when I delete and attempt to display the function, the program crashes when it reaches the spot where the deleted item once resided.

Lets say item three was the one deleted, it would output to the screen like this:
Item1 (shown)
Item2(shown)
Then it crashes

So it seems like,atleast to me,  when I use my delete function, it is leaving some kind of a 'hole' in the linked list.

The only place it does not crash when I delete from the linked list, is the head, but for some odd reason only one item is left remaining in the linked list after that.

I was wondering if someone could point where in my delete function, or my display function that is causing this error.

```
//sending a number to the function holding the position of the item.

void InventoryList::deleteNode(int num)
{
ListNode *previousNode; //To point to the previous node
ListNode *nodePtr; //to traverse the list


int number = 1;

//if the head is empty do nothing
if (!head)
{
    return;

}
//Determine if the first node is the value
if (1 == num)
{

    nodePtr = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = nodePtr;

}
else
{
    //intialize the node as head.
    nodePtr = head;


    //Skip nodes whose value is not equal to num.
    while (nodePtr != nullptr && number != num)
    {
        previousNode = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

        number++;
    }
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        previousNode = nodePtr;
        previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;

    }
}

    }
```

---

---

```
void InventoryList::displayList()
{

int x = 1;
//used to traverse the list
ListNode *nodePtr;

//setting the list equal tot he head
nodePtr = head;

//goes through the list

    while (nodePtr)
    {
        //displaying the list.
        cout << x << nodePtr->value << endl;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        x++;

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
if (nodePtr)
{
    previousNode = nodePtr;
    previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
    delete nodePtr;

}
```

You have an extra

```
    previousNode = nodePtr;
```

which means that you are effectively just setting `nodePtr->next = nodePtr->next`, which does nothing.

Just remove that line.

Comment: When I delete that I get an error saying that previousNode is potentially uninitialized, and does not let my program run. But I do see why that might be causing my problem, since I'm making the previousNode = to nodePtr, I'm essitally making previouseNode->next equal to itself right?

Comment: The reason the compiler is complaining about previousNode being potentially uninitialized is that it thinks there is a way through your code without going through your loop. As you have checked that `head` is not `nullptr` and `num` is not `1`, it will always go through your loop at least once if it reaches it. Even so, I would put `ListNode *previousNode = nullptr;` immediately above the loop rather than at the top of the function, and also double-check that it isn't nullptr at the end. This will help if later on someone changes your code and does give a way through without entering the loop

Comment: That worked, thanks alot! Also to check to see if it is nullptr, would I simply do an if statement like this:

if(!nodePtr->next=nodeptr)

Comment: @HaydenGfeller Please put parenthesis when you're not 100% sure about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). It should be `if(!(nodePtr->next=nodeptr))`

Comment: I meant use a check like `if (previousNode != nullptr)`. Also, make sure you don't use `=` when you mean `==`.